# Facebook like button not displaying og:description

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have created a like button on my website, http://www.divecerts.com.

Screen shots of the problem found at http://www.divecerts.com/screen.html

the top screenshot shows the Like button being pressed with the FB popup and the correctly scraped information.  The bottom screenshot shows what the actual post looks like on Facebook.  There you can see that everything is correct except that the descrition is blank.

I have cleared the cache at using the Facebook debug tool (linter) a few times with no luck on solving the problem.  The debugger shows the description fine BUT it does not show on the Facebook post.  I have tried viewing/liking from different Facebook accounts on different computers using different browsers with the same results.

Here is my meta code

```
 <head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="DiveCerts.com | Diver Certification Record Search" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Search for SCUBA diving certifications records from the major training agencies in one click."/>    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.divecerts.com" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.divecerts.com/img/logofb.jpg" />  
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="300">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="300">
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The debugger shows the description just fine.

Comment: exactly.  why is it not showing on the facebook post?

Comment: I'm having the same issue...anyone figure out a solution?

Comment: Can you add your actual fb like code, btw your site is down